# Sploitfun- Can't "peform" stack based buffer overflow in GDB

Tags: python, c, ubuntu, gdb, reverse-engineering

While trying to go through the tutorial in : 
https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/classic-stack-based-buffer-overflow/

I tried doing the same as he did in GDB and the result was:

> Input:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00000000004005bd in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdda8) at vuln.c:9
>   9 }

If anyone has got any idea why, I would love to hear.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I installed Ubuntu 32 bit because the -m32 wasn't working as-well, and it works fine with the 32-bit ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

> anyone's got any idea why

Because *it is supposed to*. From your reference:

```
$ gdb -q vuln
Reading symbols from /home/sploitfun/lsploits/new/csof/vuln...done.
(gdb) r `python -c 'print "A"*300'`
Starting program: /home/sploitfun/lsploits/new/csof/vuln `python -c 'print "A"*300'`
Input:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x41414141 in ?? ()
(gdb) p/x $eip
$1 = 0x41414141
```

Now, your observed result is different:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005bd in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdda8) at vuln.c:9 9 }
```

but that's because you built your binary in 64-bit mode, whereas the original was built in 32-bit mode.

If you add `-m32` flag to your compile and link commands, you should be able to follow the original more closely.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately :/ I got the same output even when I tried using -m32

Comment: @J.J It's *impossible* for you to get the *exact* same output if you compiled with `-m32`. Conclusion: either you didn't use `-m32`, or you ran old executable instead of the new one, or you got a different output (in which case you should update your question with *exact* output you got).

Comment: It's the same output with different executable. Edit: I mean, it's not showing 0x41414141 like it should, but not the EXACT same output.

Comment: @J.J Details *matter* in programming. You should edit your question and show *exact* output you get (if you want help that is).

Comment: It said that there was an error with some file.
I ended up installing the 32bit version of Ubuntu to save this pain.

If you could help me regarding something else on this exercise, I posted it here: 
[link]
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567090/x86-linux-exploit-development-sploitfun-the-very-beginning-buffer-overflow-e